# Laravel Multi language Site Database Structure

Tags: laravel, multilingual

i am in mid of a multi language website and clients requirements are he can edit any message by him self without touching the script . i tried to make several database structures but failed to get to any logical point . he want to add more languages in future the idea behind the scene is that he can edit each word on website in multiple languages eg arabic french russian chines etc . this is my table structure but i didnt get it to work as where i will store the english version of messages ? 
any help will be highly appreciated 
 [image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use this package : [laravel-translation-manager](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager)

Comment: can you please give me any idea without package . the schema of multi language database you done earlier @siliace

Comment: i found it very helpfull in making a multi language database againt each sentence  http://www.apphp.com/tutorials/images/single_translation_approach_tbl.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing it wrong way as i think . the words are counted means if there are 500 words laying in your website and you want to convert them in multiple language then you should have three tables 
for example like this a language table

tlb language

```
id ->
language -> 
status ->
```

---

second you should have a table of translation like 
tbl translation

```
id ->
```

---

third you will have a table like words 
tbl words

```
id -> primary key  
transID -> tbl translation (id) FK 
languageID -> tbl language (id) FK
sentence ->
```

Comment: yes it is making sense now i am making my structure like that